# What is wrong with my jQuery hover fadeIn effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover, fadein, fadeout

http://leongaban.com/_stack/fade/

I'm just getting into jQuery and there are tons of tutorials out there on how to do this simple fade in and out, but coming from an AS3 background it seems like my code below should work, I'm curious as to why it doesn't.

- On rollOver the Yellow box fades out
- However on rollOut the Yellow box kinda fades back in out then in again

Not sure why it 'bounces' the mouseout function... thoughts?

HTML

```
<div class="fade">
    <h2>The Title</h2>

    <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
<script>

    (function() {

        var fade = $('div.fade');

        fade.mouseover(function() {

                fade.fadeOut(500);

        });

        fade.mouseout(function() {

            fade.fadeIn(600);
        });

    })();

</script>
```

Comment: try replacing mouseover with mouseenter, and mouseout with mouseleave

Comment: +1 on mouseenter and mouseleave , also, the fadeOut fadeIn events stack up so if someone keeps whipping the mouse in and out a bunch of times, the animation will perform that many times. I would use the .animate({'opacity' : 0}) and throw the .stop() call in there as well to prevent multiple animations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you're fading out on `mouseover`. Once the fadeout is complete, the element is hidden. So the second you move the mouse, a `mouseout` event is registered, and it fades back in.

Try using `.animate({opacity: 0}, 600);`, and  `.animate({opacity: 1}, 600);` etc.

Comment: I would consider adding `.stop().animate({opacity: 0}, 600);` and `.stop().animate({opacity: 1}, 600);` as well to prevent multiple animations

Comment: Good point. Ideally, I'd just use CSS. There's actually no need for javascript at all here

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` instead.

Have a look at - http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html

Also the [hoverintent plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) could be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` functions. `mouseover` fires every time your mouse enters or leaves an element.

check the [demo](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) to see `mouseover` in action, and see why it is not the proper event.

Comment: This works better, however if I start moving the mouse around inside of the Yellow box, the animation will start going on and off